# Why can't the call member of a function be assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a transcoder for a project and came across an unusual edge case.

I have the following:

```
function a(func){
    return func.call()
}
```

for various reasons the transcoder wants to change it to:

```
function a(func){
   var tmp = func.call;
   var res = tmp()
   return res;
}
```

However, the call to `tmp()` comes back with `tmp is not a function`. If I debug and pause just by this line, `tmp` is defined as a function.

Does it have something to do with it's signature being `function call(){ [native code]}`?

Are there other functions that will trigger similar errors?

Is there a way around this, other than simply not doing it?

EDIT:
I found another case, it looks like it may be to do with the object's context:

```
a = { toString: null }.propertyIsEnumerable
a("toString")
```

throws the same error.

EDIT: some context;
I am writing the transcoder, it has a very specific use case where each line of the code is separated into it's simplest component parts. It's possible that I simply can't separate it further than this. Using the example above, func.call() is a member access operation followed by a call expression, I want to separate out the member access and call expression into two separate expressions.

Comment: *Any* method relying on the `this` value, including the native `Function.prototype.call` method, has this problem. The solution is to bind it to the object, or to not use such a shitty transcode.

Comment: Why is the transcode requiring you to change to function?

Comment: Is there a way of doing this while still splitting an expression to it's component parts? e.g., `tmp(func)` rather than `tmp()`

Comment: @SpeedyNinja - its not a requirement, I am writing the transcoder, it has a very specific use case where each line of the code is separated into it's simplest component parts. It's possible that I simply can't separate it further than this. Using the example above, `func.call()` is a member access operation followed by a call expression, I want to separate out the member access and call expression into two separate expressions.

Comment: @ZackNewsham https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call, and see the bergi's comment.

Comment: If you want to separate/parse the code, can't you just use [Tern](http://ternjs.net)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to store a method in a variable, instead of doing

```
 var f = obj.mymethod;
 f();
```

You can do

```
 var f = obj.mymethod.bind(obj);
 f();
```

Comment: Excellent - this seems to be a general solution that works on all member functions, including `call`. It's unfortunate I can't separate it further, but this will do nicely.

Comment: I'll have to join with the others in saying that its probably better if you figure out a way to not need to separate the methods like this. Javascript would prefer if the generated code just said `obj.method()` directly.

Comment: It's part of an automated tool, in this exact situation it isn't important, but it was the easiest way of explaining. Essentially the purpose of the tool is to remove any implicit control flow and replace it with explicit. It has other purposes too - but this is the preprocessing required.

Comment: using `bind` rather than `call` (or any other function) means I can add a single exception to the parsing rules, e.g., extract all function calls except `bind`

Comment: Dunno how your code transformer works but it might be worth checking if it would be possible to treat methods differently from regular functions so you can call `obj.method()` without needing to use `.bind` or similar tricks. At the very least, this would be useful for optimization.